# list indices must be integers or slices, not str error in dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running the below pipeline to ingest the data to BQ from GCS.

```
import argparse
import logging
import re
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.coders.coders import Coder
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json

# schema_data = json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json")))
# table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_data)
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json"))["schema"]))
# table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(json.load(open("myschema.json"))["schema"])

class DataIngestion:
    """A helper class which contains the logic to translate the file into
    a format BigQuery will accept."""

    def parse_method(self, string_input):
        
        values = re.split(",", re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub('"', '',
                                                         string_input)))
        row = dict(
            zip(('abv', 'ibu', 'id', 'name', 'style', 'brewery_id','ounces'),
                values))
        return row


        
def run(argv=None):
    """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        default='gs://dfdfd/bee.csv')

    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        required=False,
                        help='Output BQ table to write results to.',
                        default='dataset.table')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))

    (p
    | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input,skip_header_lines=1)
    | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
    | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
             known_args.output,
             schema=table_schema,
             # Creates the table in BigQuery if it does not yet exist.
             create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
             # Deletes all data in the BigQuery table before writing.
             write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    )
    p.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I am getting error list indices must be integers or slices, not str at the line

```
parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json"))["schema"]))
```

i have schemafile as json and trying to use the json as schema in beam code to create a table if not already present else load the data to biqquery

Comment: try `parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json"))[0]["schema"]))`

Comment: Hi @DeanVanGreunen i just used parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json"))[0]["schema"])) but am getting KeyError: 'schema', any help?

Comment: do a `print(json.dumps(json.load(open("myschema.json")))` and look at the output

Comment: this is my json file
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "abv",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "ibu",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "style",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "brewery_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "ounces",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }
]

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen could you please help me?